# OBIEE 11g EM Datasource connection to use in RPD

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, odbc, obiee

So I have created a datasource (MS SQL SERVER 2008) with JDBC settings using console of OBIEE 11g.

Settings
I have used “Database Type: MS SQL Server” and “Database Driver: Other”, the URL and driver class will be as follows,

jdbc:weblogic:sqlserver://IP:1433

weblogic.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

This connection tested fine.
I want to use this datasource in my rpd. But since my obiee is installed in linux, i can not open my repository online. Therefore, I have to create a DSN in my windows system using Datasources (ODBC). Name of DSN in my windows and DS at EM is same. So when I deploy this RPD, it deploys fine. But if i create analysis based on this, it expects an ODBC driver to be installed and throws error, Datasource name not found and no default driver specified. Which seems logical because I created the datasource in ODBC at my windows system and rpd read those settings and expects odbc. I want to use the datasource created in EM. If thats not possible, how can i resolve odbc error.

Comment: Describe what errors you get,or could you possibly provide with screenshots or error logs if any. By doing this its more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

When completing an Analysis, OBI will use a connection pool to connect to the database. This connection pool will connect from your OBI server, so you need to make sure the server is capable of making the ODBC connection too and that you've set up the connection pool properly.

On your Windows machine, where you're editing the RPD, the DSN connection will only be used for the purpose of importing database objects to the physical layer of the repository – it has nothing to do with how the BI server connects to the database at runtime.